# Use dedicated functions

Tags: wp-query

In the following page template, an additional JS script (“carousel.js”) and additional CSS file (“carousel.css”) should be loaded.
How to run these files using WordPress dedicated functions?

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Full Width Page
*
* @package WordPress
*/
get_header();
while ( have_posts() ) :
 the_post();
 the_content();
 if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
 comments_template();
 }
endwhile;
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to enqueue the script in your functions.php (If this is in a plugin, you could do a little differently).  Here's a sample:

```
 function owl_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'js/carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/carousel.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'owl_scripts' );
```

This is assuming:

1. You're using a child theme.
2. You put the carousel.js in the directory 'your-child-theme/js'.
3. You put the carousel.css in the directory 'your-child-theme/css'.